# setInterval dynamic delay in useEffect causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I really need help about this. I've tried to research this for a whole day but I can't seems to make it work.

So basically I have a component that needs to render data based on the given seconds in the setInterval function. So the delay seconds will be dynamic based on what the user sets(I call it refresh rate). Using useEffect, I fetch the said refresh rate using an api, render the api using useEffect hook and store the res.data to a state

```
  const [refreshRate, getRefreshRate] = useState(0);

  useEffect(_ => {
    axios
    .get("/api/.../refreshRate")
    .then(res => {
         getRefreshRate(res.data)
       })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  },[])
```

Then I need to set that refresh rate to be the delay seconds for the setInterval function that will be used to keep rendering the data based in the refresh rate set by the user.

```
const [refreshRate, getRefreshRate] = useState(0); // the refresh rate
const [data, getData] = useState([]); // The data that needs to re-render depending in the refreshRate State

useEffect(_ => {
 axios
    .get("/api/.../refreshRate")
    .then(res => {
         getRefreshRate(res.data)
       })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

},[])

useEffect(_ => {
   const interval = setInterval(_ => {
       axios
        .get("/api/.../getData")
        .then(res => {
             getData(res.data)
           })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
},refreshRate)

   return _ => {
    clearInterval(interval)
}
  },[])
```

But the result, it causes an infinite loop in the app. I've also tried to use Redux, with the same logic I store the refreshRate in a global state, tried to set it in the delay seconds of the setInterval function but still causes infinite loop. Is there any way to fix or improve this?

Comment: Maybe try `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is your problem, but it seems you are initializing the refreshRate with 0, which means each 0 seconds it will make a request. try to change it to 5 seconds and see if the problem persists.

`const [refreshRate, getRefreshRate] = useState(5000);`

Comment: @ThomazCapra Damn your right. It seems like the reason why it looks like an infinite loop is because the delay seconds in the setInterval are set to only MILLISECONDS. Ex: the user set the refresh rate to 8 secs. When I try to fetch the api for the refreshrate. It sets the delay to 8 MILLISECONDS rather than 8000 MILLISECONDS. Thanks man. That should fix it. You can post your answer so others can view it if they encounter this little mistake..

Comment: @ThomazCapra That won't fix the problem because if OP sets the initial value of `refreshRate` to `5000`, then `setInterval` will execute every 5 seconds but the updated value of `refreshRate` that is fetched as a result of HTTP request won't have any effect. Problem here is the missing dependency of `useEffect` hook, not the initial value of `refreshRate`.